# change innodb_log_file_size variable value for Amazon RDS MYSQL Linux server

Tags: mysql, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

we are using Amazon RDS linux server for MYSQL. what is the way to change my.cnf file variable values ??

i am trying to change innodb_log_file_size variable. Can you please update me which is the best way to change?

So please help me on this

- Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 2):

Create a new DB paramater group with your required values and attach to your RDS.

Comment: yes i did the same but innodb_log_file_size variable cont be edited, I am using AWS Management console to edit the values..

Comment: You cannot edit the value of default db parameter group ,so create a new group and modify the value and attach this group .

Comment: i was trying to edit  innodb_log_file_size variable in new variable group but it wont allow in AWS console. So which is the alternative way?

Comment: @VInayK did you find out how to do it ? i have similar  problem , i need to change size but AWS is not allowed to do it

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change that value in Aurora, the storage engine is different than rds mysql or standard mysql and optimized internally.  No need to worry about changing it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing similar issue where I need to change the value of global variable in my Amazon Aurora Serverless cluster.

[image]

As you can see in the above documentation screenshot the **innodb_log_file_size** is not a dynamic variable so it won't be available in the DB Parameter Group.

Values of these kind of non dynamic global variables can only be changed by modifying MySQL config files (my.cnf) or by modifying server startup command.

Since you are using Amazon RDS MySQL there users don't have access to config files so no you cannot modify the value of innodb_log_file_size global variable, This functionality is not available in Amazon RDS as of now.

Comment: This IS available in plain RDS MYSQL: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-configuring-parameters-for-amazon-rds-for-mysql-part-1-parameters-related-to-performance/

But not in Aurora MySQL:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Reference.html